# Laravel 8 - Show database results using for loop (not foreach)

Tags: laravel-8

Using Laravel 8: I need to display my data (images saved as image names in the db) in 8 columns on the blade page. So if I have a db row count of 18, I would equally distribute the 18 in 8 columns (+remainder if any but that is irrelevant to this q - so, 18 images/8 cols = 2 (+2 remainder)). I can do this using two for loops so:

```
@for ($col=1; $col<=8; $col++)
    @for ($img=1; $img<=$image_percolumn; $img++)
        <img src="images/{{$featuredbrands->brandLogo'}}">
    @endfor
@endfor
```

`$featuredbrands` is being passed from the controller as an array:

```
class HomeController extends Controller{

    public function index(){
        $fbrands = brands::join('subscriptions', 'brands.id','=','subscriptions.brandID')
            ->where('subscriptions.packageID','=',2)
            ->get(['brands.id','brands.brandLogo','brands.logoLink']);
    
        return view('home',[
            'featuredbrands'=>$fbrands
        ]);
    } // end function
} // end class
```

I am getting the following error for the `<img src...>` line in my blade page:

> Property [brandLogo] does not exist on this collection instance.

To test if I'm passing the data correctly to the blade page, I have tried using foreach to display the images. With foreach, I get the output in one column (so I know that data passed from controller is not the issue).

What is the correct way to reference the image field using the for loop?  If that indeed is the problem?

Comment: What is the point of the inner loop?  If you have 8 cols, you want to iterate over 8 images and then start a new row, right?  What is `$image_percolumn`?

Comment: Thx for reviewing this. The inner lloop displays the images per column so if there are 18 images, $images_percolumn is 2 (18/8). I am distributing the number of images equally in the 8 columns. so inner loop displays 2 images the we move to the outerloop for the next column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be much harder than it should be, I am sure I am missing something.

One option - convert your collection to an array, and simply reference elements by key.  Something like this:

In your Controller method:

```
return view('home', [
    'featuredbrands' => $fbrands->toArray()
]);
```

And in your view:

```
@for ($col = 0; $col <= 16; $col += 2)
    <img src="images/{{ $featuredbrands[$col]->brandLogo }}">
    <img src="images/{{ $featuredbrands[$col+1]->brandLogo }}">
@endfor
```

You could also try to do it more the Laravel way, by using the [Collection `chunk()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-chunk), though this also seems very clunky here.  Maybe something like:

```
@foreach ($featuredbrands->chunk(8) as $row)
    @foreach ($row->chunk(2) as $col)
        @foreach ($col as $brand)
            <img src="images/{{ $brand->brandLogo }}">
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks. you got me going on the right track. I have accepted the answer but needed a clarification on the chunk example you gave above. Why do we need a 3rd foreach ?and instead do $col->brandlogo. I tried and it doesn't work but wanted to know the logic. Also thx for including two examples on how to tackle this since . the knowledge will help me in future.

Comment: `chunk()` breaks a collection up into chunks.  What you get out of `chunk(2)` is a collection (think of it as an array) with 2 elements.  So to access the individual elements you still need to iterate over the chunk.

Comment: BTW you can learn more about it by debugging - try `dd($row)`, or `dd($col)`, or   `dd($brand)` inside the loops to see what that data looks like.  The docs are also very good! :-)

Comment: Got it. Cant upvote coz this was my first question so it wont allow me to upvote (something to do with min 15 reputation). PS noticed ur Q3 avatar. Loved the game back in the days. now playing QC. Thx again for the help.